# How to Debug OpenCL in VS2012 with Intel® INDE 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2012, opencl

I try to debug openCL in VS2012 using Intel® INDE 2015.
I get some trouble:

1)  I can't find "Intel SDK for OpenCL -Debugger option" in Tool menu. Where I can find it?

2) I know intel openCL SDK only support CPU context. 
 I compile OpenCL  with GPU context without any problem. but if switch to CPU context,it's fail to compiling. The error is "Ignoring -TARGETOS option - not supported for current CPU runtime version".

My CPU is i7-3770 @3.4GHZ

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install VS plugin while installing intel INDE? Have you seen [video](https://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/intel-inde-opencl-code-builder-build-debug-analyze) showing where to find the debugger? It's not in tool menu but in code-builder, if you don't see it then very likely you didn't install the plugin.

Comment: I got error "Ignoring -TARGETOS option - not supported for current CPU runtime version" when I compile cl code. What it mean?